# Search an array nested in a laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a api call that returns a set of data something like this:

```
{
"id": 97423,
"visitor_id": 231505,
"domain_sessionidx": 1,
"session_start": "2017-06-01 04:40:07",
"session_end": "2017-06-01 05:22:45",
"session_length": 2558,
"count_pages": 11,
"count_pings": 7,
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": "2017-06-12 18:59:51",
"pages": [
    1829,
    1811,
    1829,
    1501,
    1829,
    1889,
    1762,
    1686,
    1825,
    1825,
    1825
]  },....
```

I have put this into a variable and made a collection out of it:

```
$new_var = collect($result);
```

I am having a problem because I would like to access only the records in the data where pages contains the id 1762. I have been trying with:

```
$new_var->whereIn('pages',[1762])->pluck('pages')
```

but I am always getting an empty result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's probably matching objects that contain only that page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel like you need to filter your `$new_var` collection and return `true` if it's `pages` attribute contains the page you are looking for. For example:

```
$page = 1762;
$inPages = $new_var->filter(function($collection) use($page){ 
  return in_array($page, $collection->pages); 
});
```

`$inPages` should now be a subset of `$new_var` with entries that contain `1762` in their `pages` array, otherwise it will be an empty `Collection`. Check here for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections